# How can I get the index of a ordered list in a Rich Text in Contentful (Gastsby)

Tags: reactjs, contentful, richtext

I'm working on a Gatsby project that uses Contentful as its headless CMS - and rendering a particular rich text field is driving me insane.

This is an example of the document I'm trying to render - It's basically an ordered list:

```json
{
  "nodeType": "document",
  "data": {},
  "content": [
    {
      "nodeType": "ordered-list",
      "content": [
        /* item 1 */
        {
          "nodeType": "list-item",
          "content": [
            {
              "nodeType": "paragraph",
              "content": [
                {
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "Lorem 1.",
                  "marks": [],
                  "data": {}
                }
              ],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
        /* item 2 */
        {
          "nodeType": "list-item",
          "content": [
            {
              "nodeType": "paragraph",
              "content": [
                {
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "Lorem 2",
                  "marks": [],
                  "data": {}
                }
              ],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
      ],
      "data": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to render it on my Gatsby project without it's `ol` and `li` tags, like this:

```html
<div class="single-instruction">
  <header>
    <p>Step 1</p>
    <div></div>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem 1.</p>
</div>
<div class="single-instruction">
  <header>
    <p>Step 1</p>
    <div></div>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem 2.</p>
</div>
```

Following Contentful's docs, I'm trying to render this using the `@contentful/rich-text-types` package. This is how far I managed to get:

```js
import { BLOCKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types";
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text";

const options = {
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.LIST_ITEM]: (node, children) => (
      <div className="single-instruction">
        <header>
          <p>step </p>
          <div></div>
        </header>
        {children}
      </div>
    ),
  },
};

renderRichText(instructions, options)
```

Which, of course, doesn't render the step number.
I feel I'm so close now! But for the life of me, I can't seem to find the right way to render the ordered list item index. Which is something I would easily get if this were an array that I could simple map.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: My question would be — why are you using a list in the Rich Text Field if you don't want to render a list with `ol` and `li` on the front end? Perhaps a separate content type that you could link in the Rich Text field might be appropriate, so you can fetch the data via the rich-text-react-renderer and do with it what you wish?

Comment: It's because my end-user prefers a rich text first, where they can simply copy paste the content from somewhere else. I'll be still rendering a list, but appending a header with the item index before each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been facing the same issue. I used the [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) and [`counter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter()) css properties to generate the step numbers.

```css
.instructions {
  counter-increment: step;
}

.single-instruction .step::after {
  content: counter(step);
}
```

```html
<div class="instructions">
This is one list
<div class="single-instruction">
  <header>
    <p class="step"></p>
    <div></div>
  </header>
  children
</div>
<div class="single-instruction">
  <header>
    <p class="step"></p>
    <div></div>
  </header>
  children
</div>
</div>
<div>
This is another list
<div class="single-instruction">
  <header>
    <p class="step"></p>
    <div></div>
  </header>
  children
</div>
<div class="single-instruction">
  <header>
    <p class="step"></p>
    <div></div>
  </header>
  children
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I just saw your answer after I posted mine! Forgot to refresh the page. Have an upvote :)

Comment: Thanks, to both of you! :D

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could use the CSS counter() variable to add step numbers via CSS.

So your CSS might look something like:

```
.single-instruction {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.single-instruction p:after {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
}
```

The code above will add the counter on each paragraph (for the header paragraph content and the actual content paragraphs), so you'll need to add a custom class for the paragraph tags you want to target.

The only caveat is that I'm not sure how well this will work with screen readers and other assistive technology without digging deeper.

More information here: https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_counters.asp

Comment: Thanks!! :D
This solved it!